# Play Audio Through Computer's Built-in Speakers

Tags: sound, configuration, speakers, audio-jack

Is it possible to use the internal built-in speakers of a computer to play music from a device?
I am using an audio jack male to male cable

[image]

And as device I am using an FM-Radio Module (TEA5767)

[image]

But instead of connecting the module to an external speaker, I would like to use my computer's built-in speakers. Do you know how to do that on Ubuntu 18.04.2? Apparently something similar can be done on MAC OS, https://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-play-your-devices-audio-through-your-compu/

Comment: Well, that person is using an USB microphone, and I am using audio jack male to male cable .. I think it is a digital protocol vs an analog ..

Comment: Simply connect the output of your radio module to the jack line-in of the computer. Then use the `pulseaudio` tools to link line-in to speakers output. This may require the optional `pavucontrol` program (dunno) or could be done with out-of-the-box `gnome-control-center sound` /// For sure you can listen the line-in with `pactl load-module module-loopback`, reverting it with `pactl unload-module module-loopback` ///

Comment: @Delfin not really, the process of looping it back to the output should be the same

Comment: Well, it is not working, when I do pactl load-module module-loopback
it only displays 27

Comment: BTW, This is my sound card: Intel Corporation CM238 HD Audio Controller .. I don't have a jack like-in, only a Headset/speaker jack